# Bezier along Terrain Surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mathematical-optimization, bezier, raycasting

What’d be the best way to go, if i paint a bezier Curve (set start and endpoints) to Unity Terrain, and i want the curve to folow the ups and downs from the ground.

right now i partly achieve it like this,(need to connect the new Points from groundedPoints, as new Beziers)

```
int SegmentCount = Mathf.Floor(BezierLength / SegmentLength);
//Rounded to the next lower integer
var groundedPoints = new List<Vector3>();

for(int i =0; i<SegmentCount;i++){
  Vector3 p = GetPoint(BezierPoints,i / SegmentCount);
    p = p.RayCastDown();
    //RayCasting Down to get the Point on the Terrain
  if(i == 0 || i < SegmentCount -1){
    groundedPoints.Add(p);
  }else{
    if(p.y != groundedPoints[groundedPoints.Count-1].y){
      groundedPoints.Add(p);
      }
   }
}
```

it’s right now kind of not that accurate, but it, doesn’t have to be a real accurate solution.

Maybe someone can give me a hint? thanks

Comment: Try this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF04Fi9OCPc&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0d8aDaovNztYf6iTChHzrHP

Comment: hm, thats not about 3d Cubic Beziers, sorry didnt mentioned that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly i would recommend using [Centripetal Catmull–Rom spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) because it follows points more strictly, and need less points to generate(also only draws between p1 and p2), but i dont know what you want to achieve so:

I would transform your bezier into a 2d bezier, and only work in 2d space with it, then when you draw(render it visually) you give it a Y value by using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain.SampleHeight.html

I do this with my splines, and it gives a quite accurate spline in the end(road generation)

PLEASE NOTE!:
That the implicit Vector2 and Vector3 conversion will not fit your needs, you need to add an extension method to convert Vector3 to Vector2 :)
(Vector(x,y,z) will be Vector(x,y) but you need Vector(x,z))

**Edit 1:**

Codesample how to read out a terrain actual height, via `Terrain.SampleHeight();` by a `Vector2` coordinate that you are sure is above a terrain, if the `Vector2` is not above the terrain it will give you back null or the closets terrain height to it im not sure which one atm(can't test it now) :)

```
public static float GetPoint_On_Terrain(Vector2 point){
    float terrainHeightAtPoint = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.y));
    return new Vector3(point.x, terrainHeightAtPoint,point.y);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion this will be indeed a method to replace a recast at a given Point. => but all those Results are use alot of power. which leads me to Unity Job System => therefor I'll read out from Terrain GetHeights *(float[y,x])* which I can then use in a ParalellFor Job to test agains a given Point and move on! 

*this is my RoadMap now* but thank's for the Suggestion which lead me there.

Comment: Afaik, terrain getheight is slower then, sampleheight cos it reads out from your heightmap, meanwhile sampleheight is just a 2nd derivative, so are u sure this is what it slowes down your process?, im generating a spline at runtime with 7800 points around 350 fps, with its offsets, its 7800 * 3 sampleheight @dan_wipf

Comment: well I guess you're right! => result pictures are here if interested [Github](https://github.com/danwipf/Questions-Stuff-Unity-Answers-and-Stackoverflow/tree/master/StackOverflow)